# Array from values of data_url attributes of LI tags

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, custom-data-attribute

need make array from values of data_url attributes of LI tags.
my html code:

```
<li class='has-sub'>
    <a href="#"><span class="record-date"><?=$key?></span><span class="record-num"><span id="records_quantity"><?=$quantity?></span>   записей</span></a>
    <ul>
        <li id="1" data-url="mp3/1.mp3">
            <span class="button-play"><input type="hidden" name="file_name" value="     mp3/1.mp3"></span>
            <span class="record-time">11:30 - 11:45</span>
            <a href="#" class="record-del" id="1"></a>
            <a href="mp3/1.mp3" class="record-load" download></a>
        </li>
        <li id="2" data-url="mp3/2.mp3">
            <span class="button-play"><input type="hidden" name="file_name" value="      mp3/1.mp3"></span>
            <span class="record-time">11:45 - 11:55</span>
            <a href="#" class="record-  del" id="1"></a>
            <a href="mp3/2.mp3" class="record-load" download></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

How to make right array?

Comment: what you have tried for that?

Comment: This isn't a code writing factory....you should be making attempts and showing us what you tried. The idea is to help you with your code...not for people here to do your work for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()` function along with `.get()`:

```
var datauriarr = $('li[data-url]').map(function(){
   return $(this).data('url');
}).get();
```

```js
$(function(){
var datauriarr = $('li[data-url]').map(function(){
   return $(this).data('url');
}).get();
alert(datauriarr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class='has-sub'>
   <a href="#"><span class="record-date"><?=$key?></span><span class="record-num"><span id="records_quantity"><?=$quantity?></span>   записей</span></a>
<ul>
<li id="1" data-url="mp3/1.mp3">
    <span class="button-play"><input type="hidden" name="file_name" value="     mp3/1.mp3"></span>
    <span class="record-time">11:30 - 11:45</span><a href="#" class="record-del" id="1"></a><a href="mp3/1.mp3" class="record-load" download></a>
</li>
 <li id="2" data-url="mp3/2.mp3">
    <span class="button-play"><input type="hidden" name="file_name" value="      mp3/1.mp3"></span>
    <span class="record-time">11:45 - 11:55</span><a href="#" class="record-  del" id="1"></a><a href="mp3/2.mp3" class="record-load" download></a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```